# Why do my python functions appear to be calling out of order?

Tags: python, function

I have been writing code for a game of Tic-Tac-Toe and I imported the `clear_output` function to clear the board between turns.

When I don't have the `clear_output()` function in the code, the script runs as I expect, from Top to Bottom.

When I include the `clear_output()` function, it sometimes calls the `play_position()` function before the `show_board()`.

`play_position()` requests an input, while `show_board()` just uses a `print()` function.

In the error attached, the input bar should be **below** the game board.

Any idea why this would happen? I thought python executed single functions in order. Equally, any idea how I can fix this?
One alternative I considered was \n*100 which would effectively clear each time, but it's a bit less elegant.

I am using the Jupyter Notebook in Google Chrome - not sure if this impacts?

edit: In the next cell, I call the `play()` function to execute the full code. The 'Code' below is my sequence of functions that the `play()` function should execute.

Code:

```
gameon = True
while gameon:
    reset()
    player_set()
    while win == False:
        clear_output()
        show_board()
        play_position()
        win_check()
    end_game()
    gameon = game_on()
```

[Example error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpHe6.png)

Full code:

```
def play():
    
    from IPython.display import clear_output
    import time
    
    def game_on():
        gameon = None
        while gameon not in acceptables:
            gameon = input("Would you like to play again? (Y or N)").upper()
        
            if gameon == "Y":
                return True
            elif gameon == "N":
                print("OK \nI hope you enjoyed playing.")
                return False
    
    #############################
        
    def player_set():
        global Player_1
        global Player_2
        Player_1 = ""
        while Player_1 not in Teams:
            Player_1 = input("Which counter would you like to play with? (X or O)   ").upper()

        if Player_1 == "X":
            Player_2 = "O"
        else:
            Player_2 = "X"
        player = 1
    
    #############################

    def win_check():
        global win
        
        a = display_board[0]
        b = display_board[1]
        c = display_board[2]
        d = display_board[3]
        e = display_board[4]
        f = display_board[5]
        g = display_board[6]
        h = display_board[7]
        i = display_board[8]
    
    #top corner
        if a==b==c or a==d==g:
            if a == "X":
                clear_output()
                print("Team X won!")
                win = True
            elif a == "O":
                clear_output()
                print("Team O won!")
                win = True
    #central
        elif a==e==i or b==e==h or c==e==g or d==e==f:
            if e == "X":
                clear_output()
                print("Team X won!")
                win = True
            elif e == "O":
                clear_output()
                print("Team O won!")
                win = True
    #bottom corner
        elif g==h==i or c==f==i:
            if i == "X":
                clear_output()
                print("Team X won!")
                win = True
            elif i == "O":
                clear_output()
                print("Team O won!")
                win = True
                
    # Full board check
    
        if a!=" " and b!=" " and c!=" " and d!=" " and e!=" " and f!=" " and g!=" " and h!=" " and i!=" " and win!= True:
            clear_output()
            print("This is a draw.")
            win = "Draw"
            
    #############################
    
    def reset():
        example_board = ["X","X","O","O","X","O","X","O","X"]
        global blank_board
        blank_board =[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
        Teams = ["X","O","o","x"]
        global player
        player = 1
        gameon = True
        play_index = 100
        global index_board
        index_board = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
        global display_board
        display_board = blank_board
        global win
        win = False
        
    #############################
    
    def show_board():

        a = display_board[0]
        b = display_board[1]
        c = display_board[2]
        d = display_board[3]
        e = display_board[4]
        f = display_board[5]
        g = display_board[6]
        h = display_board[7]
        i = display_board[8]
        print("Below is the board for the game of Noughts and Crosses.\nThe positions are labelled. \nWhen choosing a square to play in, use these numbers as an index.\n\n")
        print("Index Board: "+"    "*4+"Game Board:")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
        print("  1  |  2  |  3  "+"   "*4+f"  {a}  |  {b}  |  {c} ")
        print("_____|_____|_____"+"   "*4+"_____|_____|_____")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
        print("  4  |  5  |  6  "+"   "*4+f"  {d}  |  {e}  |  {f} ")
        print("_____|_____|_____"+"   "*4+"_____|_____|_____")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
        print("  7  |  8  |  9  "+"   "*4+f"  {g}  |  {h}  |  {i} ")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")

    #############################    
    
    def play_position():
        time.sleep(0.04)
        choice = 100
        global player
        while choice not in index_board:
            choice = input("Which slot would you like to choose?     ")
            if choice in index_board:
                play_index = int(choice)-1
                if display_board[play_index] == " ":
                    if player == 1:
                        display_board[play_index] = Player_1
                        player = 2
                    elif player ==2:
                        display_board[play_index] = Player_2
                        player = 1
                    return player
                else:
                    print("This box is occupied, please choose another")
                    choice = 100
            
            else:
                print("Try again. You must choose from one of the options shown on the index board. \nOptions are: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9")

    ############################# 
    
    def end_game():
        
        a = display_board[0]
        b = display_board[1]
        c = display_board[2]
        d = display_board[3]
        e = display_board[4]
        f = display_board[5]
        g = display_board[6]
        h = display_board[7]
        i = display_board[8]

        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
        print("  1  |  2  |  3  "+"   "*4+f"  {a}  |  {b}  |  {c} ")
        print("_____|_____|_____"+"   "*4+"_____|_____|_____")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
        print("  4  |  5  |  6  "+"   "*4+f"  {d}  |  {e}  |  {f} ")
        print("_____|_____|_____"+"   "*4+"_____|_____|_____")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
        print("  7  |  8  |  9  "+"   "*4+f"  {g}  |  {h}  |  {i} ")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
    
    ###########################
    
    gameon = True
    while gameon:
        reset()
        player_set()
        while win == False:
            clear_output()
            show_board()
            play_position()
            win_check()
        end_game()
        gameon = game_on()
```

Comment: I copied the code you pasted. As pasted nothing happens. The reason is functions run in the order they are **called**. As pasted, due, to indents, there is only one function def play() and there is no code to call it. So, I would start by checking the indentation.

Comment: In jupyter notebook, cells do run in order. However, they must define functions before a later cell can call the functions.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. This is my code for the play() function. I wanted a clean end-user experience. So I run this cell once to set up all my functions, then simply call 'play()' in its own cell.

The functions are all defined within the play() function. Is it better practice to define functions all separately, then call within one?

Answer (score 0):

I created a jupyter notebook by copying the code to Cell1. Cell 2 has only play().

An error occurred Teams was missing. Below is revised code for cell 1.

```
def play():
    
    from IPython.display import clear_output
    import time
    
    def game_on():
        gameon = None
        while gameon not in acceptables:
            gameon = input("Would you like to play again? (Y or N)").upper()
        
            if gameon == "Y":
                return True
            elif gameon == "N":
                print("OK \nI hope you enjoyed playing.")
                return False
    
    #############################
        
    def player_set():
        global Player_1
        global Player_2
        Player_1 = ""
        while Player_1 not in Teams:
            Player_1 = input("Which counter would you like to play with? (X or O)   ").upper()

        if Player_1 == "X":
            Player_2 = "O"
        else:
            Player_2 = "X"
        player = 1
    
    #############################

    def win_check():
        global win
        
        a = display_board[0]
        b = display_board[1]
        c = display_board[2]
        d = display_board[3]
        e = display_board[4]
        f = display_board[5]
        g = display_board[6]
        h = display_board[7]
        i = display_board[8]
    
    #top corner
        if a==b==c or a==d==g:
            if a == "X":
                clear_output()
                print("Team X won!")
                win = True
            elif a == "O":
                clear_output()
                print("Team O won!")
                win = True
    #central
        elif a==e==i or b==e==h or c==e==g or d==e==f:
            if e == "X":
                clear_output()
                print("Team X won!")
                win = True
            elif e == "O":
                clear_output()
                print("Team O won!")
                win = True
    #bottom corner
        elif g==h==i or c==f==i:
            if i == "X":
                clear_output()
                print("Team X won!")
                win = True
            elif i == "O":
                clear_output()
                print("Team O won!")
                win = True
                
    # Full board check
    
        if a!=" " and b!=" " and c!=" " and d!=" " and e!=" " and f!=" " and g!=" " and h!=" " and i!=" " and win!= True:
            clear_output()
            print("This is a draw.")
            win = "Draw"
            
    #############################
    
    def reset():
        example_board = ["X","X","O","O","X","O","X","O","X"]
        global blank_board
        blank_board =[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
        Teams = ["X","O","o","x"]
        global player
        player = 1
        gameon = True
        play_index = 100
        global index_board
        index_board = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
        global display_board
        display_board = blank_board
        global win
        win = False
        return Teams
        
    #############################
    
    def show_board():

        a = display_board[0]
        b = display_board[1]
        c = display_board[2]
        d = display_board[3]
        e = display_board[4]
        f = display_board[5]
        g = display_board[6]
        h = display_board[7]
        i = display_board[8]
        print("Below is the board for the game of Noughts and Crosses.\nThe positions are labelled. \nWhen choosing a square to play in, use these numbers as an index.\n\n")
        print("Index Board: "+"    "*4+"Game Board:")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
        print("  1  |  2  |  3  "+"   "*4+f"  {a}  |  {b}  |  {c} ")
        print("_____|_____|_____"+"   "*4+"_____|_____|_____")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
        print("  4  |  5  |  6  "+"   "*4+f"  {d}  |  {e}  |  {f} ")
        print("_____|_____|_____"+"   "*4+"_____|_____|_____")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
        print("  7  |  8  |  9  "+"   "*4+f"  {g}  |  {h}  |  {i} ")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")

    #############################    
    
    def play_position():
        time.sleep(0.04)
        choice = 100
        global player
        while choice not in index_board:
            choice = input("Which slot would you like to choose?     ")
            if choice in index_board:
                play_index = int(choice)-1
                if display_board[play_index] == " ":
                    if player == 1:
                        display_board[play_index] = Player_1
                        player = 2
                    elif player ==2:
                        display_board[play_index] = Player_2
                        player = 1
                    return player
                else:
                    print("This box is occupied, please choose another")
                    choice = 100
            
            else:
                print("Try again. You must choose from one of the options shown on the index board. \nOptions are: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9")

    ############################# 
    
    def end_game():
        
        a = display_board[0]
        b = display_board[1]
        c = display_board[2]
        d = display_board[3]
        e = display_board[4]
        f = display_board[5]
        g = display_board[6]
        h = display_board[7]
        i = display_board[8]

        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
        print("  1  |  2  |  3  "+"   "*4+f"  {a}  |  {b}  |  {c} ")
        print("_____|_____|_____"+"   "*4+"_____|_____|_____")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
        print("  4  |  5  |  6  "+"   "*4+f"  {d}  |  {e}  |  {f} ")
        print("_____|_____|_____"+"   "*4+"_____|_____|_____")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
        print("  7  |  8  |  9  "+"   "*4+f"  {g}  |  {h}  |  {i} ")
        print("     |     |     "+"   "*4+"     |     |     ")
    
    ###########################
    
    gameon = True
    while gameon:
        Teams = reset()
        player_set()
        while win == False:
            clear_output()
            show_board()
            play_position()
            win_check()
        end_game()
        gameon = game_on()
```

reset now returns a value for Teams. player_set needs this value.

```
    gameon = True
    while gameon:
        Teams = reset()
        player_set()
        while win == False:
            clear_output()
            show_board()
            play_position()
            win_check()
        end_game()
        gameon = game_on()
```

Comment: RE:  Is it better practice to define functions all separately, then call within one? Defining functions separately can help with making implementation easier to understand and troubleshoot